# R - grouping by ID, finding the max value in column two (delete all other) and keep value of third column as well

Tags: r

I have a dataset of three columns and roughly 300000 rows:

```
#Person ID# ##Likelihood of Risk## ###Year the survey was taken###
```

Each Person has taken part multiple times and I only want the most recent likelihood of Risk.
I wanted to figure that out by grouping the Person ID and then finding the max year.
That did not work out but I rather ended up having still multiple identical person ID's.
To continue working I need one specific value of Likelihood of Risk for each ID.

```
Riskytest <- Risk_Adult %>% group_by(pid,A_risk) %>% summarize(max=max(syear))
```

Comment: Could you provide sample data?

Comment: `group_by(pid,A_risk)` will give you one row per unique `pid` and `A_risk` combination. If you want only one row per `pid`, then leave `A_risk` out of the grouping and `group_by(pid)` only. And `max(syear)` will give you the maximum values of the `syear` column... you say you want the max year but I'm guessing you want the year with the maximum `A_risk`? Maybe `Risk_Adult %>% group_by(pid) %>% slice_max(A_risk)`? Very hard to tell with no sample input nor desired output in the question...

Answer (score 0):

```
Riskytest <- Risk_Adult %>% 
             group_by(pid) %>% 
             slice_max(syear) %>% 
             ungroup()
```